# What's the closure of $(a,b)$ in discrete topology on the real number $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In my opinion, by definition, the closure of $(a,b)$ in discrete topology on the real number $\mathbb{R}$ is $(a,b)$. However, I just saw the answer for this question is $[a,b]$. Now I am not sure which one.

Answer (score 4):

The closure of any set $S\subseteq X$ when $X$ is equipped with the discrete topology $\mathcal P(X)$ is $S$.

This is because in a discrete topology, all sets are open, and so all sets are closed. This means $S$ is closed, and the closure of any closed set is the set itself.

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For any point $x$ not in $(a,b)$ , $\{x\}$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ not intersecting $(a,b)$ thus no point outside can be in closure and each point of $(a,b)$ will be in closure since nbd of each point will intersect $(a,b)$ at least at that point itself.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach is the following. The discrete topology is induced by the discrete metric.

Now sequences $x_n$ converge to $x$ in the discrete metric if and only if there exists $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n=x$ for all $n\geq n_0$. Consequently, $(a,b)$ is the closure of itself in this topology.